# Problem upgrading ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade

I need help!
Been offered upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 LTS. I pressed yes, let the automatic update run and as a result I cannot use my computer cause the system does not load after start. It just freezes. Just blinking cursor at that's it. Never had such a problem with any of the previous updates.

Comment: Easiest way to fix is to fresh install 20.04 from a live USB.

Comment: Do you see login prompt on Ctrl+Alt+F3?

Answer (score 0):

I would download an ISO of Ubuntu 18.04 onto a thumb drive. Boot from the thumb drive, then mount the root partition of your computer read-only. Check the contents of `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/dmesg` on that drive, as well as any other logs that seem relevant. Pay attention to the modification times on those files. Google for any error messages and post your findings here.

At the very least, booting from the ISO and mounting the drive should allow you to back up the data from the drive onto an external hard drive or something. Once your data is safe, you can do a fresh install.

Edit: ISO of 20.04 is probably a better place to start.